# Connecting MQ version 9 using JAVA with SSL

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

I tried to connect MQ version 9 using the following code.

```
/**
 * Java class to connect to MQ. Post and Retrieve messages.
 *
 */
public class MQClientTest {

    String qMngrStr = "";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String queueName = "qname";
    String hostName = "hostName ";
    int port = 1234;
    String channel = "channel";
    String sslCiphersuite="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";
    //message to put on MQ.
    String msg = "WelCome to MQ.";
    //Create a default local queue.
    MQQueue queue;
    MQQueueManager qManager;

    /**
     * Initialize the MQ
     *
     */
    public void init(){

        //Set MQ connection credentials to MQ Envorinment.
         MQEnvironment.hostname = hostName;
         MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
         MQEnvironment.port = port;
         MQEnvironment.userID = user;
         MQEnvironment.password = password;
         MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite= sslCiphersuite;
       //  MQEnvironment.sslFipsRequired=true;
         //set transport properties.
         MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQConstants.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);

         try {
             //initialize MQ manager.
            qManager = new MQQueueManager(qMngrStr);
        } catch (MQException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("queue manager issue");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to put message to MQ.
     *
     */
    public void putAndGetMessage(){

        int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT; 
        try {
            queue = qManager.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

            MQMessage putMessage = new MQMessage();
            putMessage.writeUTF(msg);

            //specify the message options...
            MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); 
            // accept 
            // put the message on the queue
            queue.put(putMessage, pmo);

            System.out.println("Message is put on MQ.");

        catch (MQException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("MQexception");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("IOexception");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception");}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Processing Main...");

        MQClientTest clientTest = new MQClientTest();
        System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
        // Enabling SSL debug to view the communication
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake");

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","client.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","clientpass");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","client.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","clientpass");
        //initialize MQ.
        clientTest.init();

        //put and retreive message from MQ.
        clientTest.putAndGetMessage();

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

}
```

but i am getting the following error:

> MQJE001: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2393'.

i have tried setting the system variable com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings to false. and also have added the ssl name in MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite.

I have read the mapping for ciphermapping also on IBM website. Can not find any more solutions. Please help if anybody knows about this?

Thanks

Comment: RC 2393 is MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR, which in the case of an MQ Java/Java application usually means that the JRE's TLS socket library (Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE)) is unhappy with something in the TLS configuration.

The exception reported from JSSE should be available as a linked exception from the resulting MQException, and will give more information on the nature of the problem - are you able to modify your application to print out the linked exception as well?

Comment: My queuemanger name is null, so it is giving an error to get the queue manager object. How should i resolve this?

Comment: @user - the queue manager name supplied to the MQQueueManager constructor must the actual name of the queue manager you want to connect to.

If the constant values (hostname, port, channel etc.) in the code above are the actual values you are compiling with, then they all need changing to be the correct values for the target queue manager.

Comment: What is the exact java version you are using? Ex 1.8 0-124.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is probably with the JRE not permitting 256 cipher suites, not MQ. See https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/189995/why-do-i-get-amq9771-2393-ssl-initialization-error/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#footnote1-1

I would suggest to upgrade your Java JDK to the latest and try again.